# How to check boolean getter with AssertJ?

Tags: java, unit-testing, assertj

It looks very cool

```
assertThat(yoda).is(jedi);
```

until you don't know what is `yoda` and `jedi`. But suppose

```
yoda instanceof Person
```

where

```
interface Person {
    boolean isJedi();
}
```

Then how actually check `isJedi` with `AssertJ`?

In conventional `JUnit` I would write

```
assertTrue( yoda.isJedi() );
```

but what in `AssertJ`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
assertThat(yoda.isJedi()).isTrue()
```

Comment: Great! But why examples demonstrate different? May be I can rapidly compose Condition for yoda somehow?

Comment: Conditions are used to express more complex checks that you want to reuse, in your case it is a simple boolean check that is (hopefully) already supported.

Answer (score 1):

assertThat(yoda.isJedi()).isEqualTo(true);